# Composer Best Practise?

Tags: composer-php

I work in a team with ~15 developers and we've been asking ourselves: *What is the best practise to work with composer?*

Our `composer.json` has ~5 Packages. We use Bamboo as a Continous Integration system and Subversion.

Today, we run `composer self-update` / `composer update` and commit the `vendor` folder into the repository.

It feels kind of wrong to do that. What is the best practise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You put the requirements (dev and normal) in the `composer.json` file
2. You run `composer update` to update all dependencies
3. This command creates a `composer.lock` file, which contains which versions of the dependencies is used.
4. Commit that file and exclude (ignore) the `vendor/` directory
5. Whenever you want to install the dependencies, you run `composer install`. This will install all dependencies with the versions stored in the `composer.lock` file. This means that everyone have the same versions.
6. Once in a week, someone run `composer update` to update all dependencies and create a new `composer.lock` file with the updated versions.
7. This file gets committed
8. Everyone runs `composer install` (once a day or once in 2 days) and gets the new versions installed.

Comment: @CBergau I meaned exclude instead of included, fixed it now

Comment: Sounds good, but this also means that composer must be used in production unless a package is created. We run SVN tags in prod, where this approach would not fit that well.

Comment: *"this also means that composer must be used in production unless a package is created"* - that's exactly something Composer is created for: Handling dependencies on the prod and dev server

Comment: Ok. I'm trying to figure out if the actual update process is atomical. Are the updated dependencies updated/activated once everything is downloaded and checked OK, or is each dependency updated as soon as it's downloaded? Having trouble finding docs on that. (Should probably post a question..)